# interpretation of logarithmic in the dimension

Tags: limits, logarithms, polylogarithm

I'm reading a paper that says

"$\ Cn^{6/5}r \log n $ is not logarithmic or polylogarithmic in the dimension and one would like to know if results closer to the $\ nr \log n$ limit are possible."

Isn't it logarithmic in the dimension since the $\log n$ is there in both cases? (The limit isn't logarithmic in the dimension anyway so why bother pointing out that it isn't so in the first case?)

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it logarithmic in the dimension since the $\log n$ is there in both cases?

The presence of $\log n$ does not make something logarithmic in $n$. The bound of the form $)(\log n)$ does. Since it is not true that $n^{6/5}\log n =O(\log n)$, the expression is not logarithmic. It is not polylogarithmic either, since there is no bound of the form $n^{6/5}\log n =O((\log n)^k)$  for any fixed $k$.

(To prove the latter claim, compare the logarithms of both sides: $\frac65 \log n + \log\log n$ is linear in $\log n$, while $k\log \log n$ grows much slower.)

> The limit isn't logarithmic in the dimension anyway so why bother pointing out  ...

Not clear to me either. Maybe this paragraph makes more sense in wider context.